# QGIS save selected layers to shapefiles by python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I wrote the code below to save selected layers in the `layerTree` to a folder by Python, some of them are temporary layers, I don't know if it matters, and my main purpose is to save those temporary layers altogether. The code executed without error, but nothing in the direct folder:

```
for lyrs in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
    path = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/A_work/Scripts"
    os.chdir(path)
    basename=lyrs.name()
    SHPname = basename +'.shp'
    SHPpath= path + '/' + SHPname
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyrs,SHPpath,'utf-8',lyrs.crs(),'SHP', layerOptions=['ESRI Shapefile'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Driver name` parameter should be `'ESRI Shapefile'` instead of `'SHP'` for shapefiles. And no need `layerOptions` here.

Change

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    lyrs,SHPpath,'utf-8',lyrs.crs(),'SHP', layerOptions=['ESRI Shapefile'])
```

to

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    lyrs, SHPpath, 'utf-8', lyrs.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Answer (score 7):

and in addition to Kadir: you should use `writeAsVectorFormatV3` since QGIS Version 3.20. The code then looks like

```
for lyrs in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
   path = "C:/tonne/test"
   os.chdir(path)
   basename=lyrs.name()
   SHPname = basename +'.shp'
   SHPpath= path + '/' + SHPname
   options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
   options.driverName = 'ESRI Shapefile'
   context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
   # since QGIS 3.20 you should use writeAsVectorFormatV3
   QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(lyrs, SHPpath, context, options)
```

Comment: if you have a look to the api docs it should be ok: https://www.qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3