# Different Graduated Symbology Class & Color for 100's of Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have hundreds of layers that I would like to apply a graduated symbology using the Natural Jenks Algorithm for each.  If I copy and paste a style for the layer group the classes and colors are the same because it doesn't update the classes or randomly pick a color for the selected layer.  I have tried running 'set layer style' as a batch process with a style file (*.qml), but it also produces the same result as the copy/paste method.

Below is the type of result I would like.  Each cluster is a separate layer.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can load a saved qml style and apply it to each layer.
While applying it we can modify the Color to be a random values.

The script below works as follows:

1. Apply the saved .qml style (with jenks etc) to the active layer **(change the uri)**
2. Loop through each layer and clone the style to that layer
3. Modify the Start color variable for each layer, calculate the class breaks, and refresh the layer

```
from random import randrange

#load source of rendering:
uri = ".../Documents/BelcoStyle.qml"
sourcelayer = iface.activeLayer()
sourcelayer.loadNamedStyle(uri) 
classcount = len([s.color() for s in sourcelayer.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())])
renderer = sourcelayer.renderer()
renderer.updateClasses(sourcelayer,classcount)
print(renderer.sourceColorRamp().color1().getRgb() )
sourcelayer.reload()

i=0
#loop through each layer in the project
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    #ignore not vector layers and the source layer
    if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)and layer.name()!= sourcelayer.name():
        i+=1
        print('\n'+'RUN:%s, '%str(i)+layer.name())
        #
        #get layers by name
        destlayer = layer
        print(destlayer.name())
        #
        #clone renderer from source layer to current layer
        rendervar= renderer.clone()
        print(rendervar.sourceColorRamp().color1().getRgb() )
        destlayer.setRenderer(rendervar) 
        #
        #CHANGE Start colour randomly
        color1 = QColor (randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255))
        color2 = QColor (255, 255, 255)
        destlayer.renderer().updateColorRamp(QgsGradientColorRamp(color1, color2))
        destlayer.renderer().updateClasses(destlayer,classcount)
        print(rendervar.sourceColorRamp().color1().getRgb() )
        destlayer.reload()

iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

[image: Input Output Image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have cleaned up to remove redundancy. Of course the breaks need updating, will test and amend code.

Comment: I'm new to using python in qgis: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
NameError: name 'renderer' is not defined

Comment: I've fixed the code, modified the start. I had edited a lined by mistake when editing the content.
We need the line: renderer = sourcelayer.renderer()

Comment: Thanks, it works now; however, the color ramp needs to be inverted.  The high values need to be on the darker end of the spectrum.

Comment: @MJM you can simply switch `color1` and `color2` in `QgsGradientColorRamp(color1, color2)` to invert the ramp.

Comment: Is it easy enough to just loop through a selected layer in Layers?

Comment: You can change the for loop to be something like: 'for layer in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():'

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152537/programmatically-get-selected-layers-from-the-qgis-legend
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450992/qgis-save-selected-layers-to-shapefiles-by-python-console